# How to resize a UWP ListView to fit Page after resizing Page?

Tags: listview, uwp, window-resize

I am working on two Windows 10 UWP Store apps that both contain a ListView.
My problem is that when I resize the Page and make it smaller, the ListView does not change size. Thus a part of the ListView becomes inaccessible to the user.
In order to research this I made a very simple app and only changed the XAML code.

This is how the XAML code looks like:

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Height="600" Width="340"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Text="Line 1"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 2"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 3"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 4"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 5"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 6"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 7"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 8"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 9"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 0"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 11"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 12"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 13"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 14"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 15"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 16"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 17"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 18"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 19"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 20"></TextBlock>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

How to replicate:

- Create a Windows 10 Store app
- Alter the MainPage as shown above
- Run the program
- Resize the window height to make it lower than the ListView
- Try to scroll down to Line 20

Expected behaviour:

```
The ListView should be resized

Line 20 should be accessible
```

Actual behaviour:

```
The ListView is not resized

Line 20 cannot be accessed
```

I have done similar programs in Windows API:s prior to UWP, and thought this should be easy, but after reading the MSDN documentations for days and checking forums without success I realize there must be some new philosophies behind UWP that escapes my understanding. It is probably something easy I have missed.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified height and width for the page which makes the page size constant. I have removed the page width and height attributes. It works now. And regarding the scroll-viewer, **you don't need a scroll-viewer to scroll through the items of the list-view**.

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Text="Line 1"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 2"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 3"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 4"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 5"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 6"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 7"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 8"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 9"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 0"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 11"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 12"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 13"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 14"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 15"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 16"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 17"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 18"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 19"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 20"></TextBlock>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Ah, the size for the Page was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: How do I mark your answer as the correct answer and give you credit for your help (I'm new to stackoverflow).

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think is wrapping `ScrollViewer` outside `ListView`.
Or remove `Height="600"` attribute on `ListView`.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ListView x:Name="listView" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="600" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="340" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBlock Text="Line 1"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 2"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 3"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 4"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 5"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 6"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 7"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 8"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 9"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 0"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 11"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 12"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 13"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 14"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 15"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 16"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 17"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 18"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 19"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 20"></TextBlock>    
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried both those suggestions, but it still has the same problem.

Comment: What problem do you encounter ?

Comment: When I resize the window, the Page, the ListView does not change size. If the window is smaller than the ListView, parts of the ListView cannot be seen. I need the ListView to be the same size as the Page at all times.

Comment: Try remove `ScrollViewer` control, and remove `Height` and `Width` attribute in `listView` from my answer.

Comment: Then if I do that, I'm back to square zero. Anyway, I found something called 'VerticalContentAlignment' witch sounded interesting, but after a lot of fiddeling still no cigar.

Comment: Your initial code, `ListView` has fixed `height` and `width`, maybe my answer is irrelevant now.